# Once i Login why i am not getting HomeViewController as Rootviewcontroller in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, rootviewcontroller

In **appdelegate i am getting UserId**.. means i am login but when i run second time i am not getting homeviewcontroller as rootviewcontroller why?  still it shows phonenumviewcontroller

```
navigationcontroller -> phonenumviewcontroller -> registrationiewcontroller -> homeviewcontroller
```

**In storyboard navigationcontroller is initialviewcontroller**

In registrationviewcontroller i am getting `userId` which i have saved in keychain.
I dont have `signout` button so i have written code like below in registrationiewcontroller

```
 do {
       let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String:AnyObject]
       print("terms and condition JSON \(json)")
       let jsonObj: String = json["Success"] as? String ?? ""
       if jsonObj == "true" {
        let userID: String=jsonObj?["userId"] as? String ?? ""

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           KeychainWrapper.standard.set(userID, forKey: "USERID")
           let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController;
            UserDefaults.standard.set("NoLogout", forKey:"Signout")
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
                    }
                    }
         }
```

no signout button so added this code in registrationviewcontroller

```
  UserDefaults.standard.set("NoLogout", forKey:"Signout")
```

**this code in appdelegate**: getting userId but still homeviewcontroller is not coming as rootviewcontroller, only phonenumviewcontroller is coming why?

```
  var savedUserId: String?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    savedUserId = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "USERID")
    KeychainWrapper.standard.set(savedUserId ?? "", forKey: "PersonalID")
    print("appdelegate userid \(savedUserId)")
    logOutString = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Signout") as NSString? ?? "" as NSString
    if logOutString.isEqual(to: "NoLogout") {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewcontroller = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController")
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewcontroller)
        self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    else {
    }
    return true
}
```

once registration is completed i need rootviewcontroller as homeviewcontroller... how to get that, please help me with code

Comment: Did you remove the root view controller from plist?

Comment: So, what exactly are you trying to achieve but not able to?

Comment: @AnkurLahiry.. i didn't add root viewcontroller in plist? is it need to add.. actually i dont know.. how to add

Comment: @Frankenstein once i register or login with registred mobile num.. i need to show homeviewcontroller.. if i stop and run again need to show `homeviewcontroller` until i delete the app.. but all the time first phonenumviewcontroller is coming

Comment: Where is the code that creates a "phonenumviewcontroller" and installs it into the window?

Answer (score 0):

From whatever I've gathered, here's what you need to do:
In AppDelegate:

```swift
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let isUserLoggedIn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn") // Give you own check to see if user is logged in

        window = UIWindow()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let viewController =  isUserLoggedIn ? MainViewController() : LoginViewController()
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)

        return true
    }
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .green
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleUserLoggedOut))
    }

    @objc func handleUserLoggedOut() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginViewController())
    }
}

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .red
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Login", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleUserLoggedIn))
    }

    @objc func handleUserLoggedIn() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainViewController())
    }
}
```

This is only a skeleton. Give both controller different background colours and button action to call `handleUserLoginIn` and `handleUserLoggedOut` on respective controllers and see how it works. Play around with it and figure out.

Note: keyWindow is deprecated so you need to use this instead at all places.

```swift
let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
        .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
        .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
        .compactMap({$0})
        .first?.windows
        .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
```

Edit: I've also added the `login`, `logout` buttons and set `backgroundColors` for you to see for yourself the result.